# Did Prophet Mohammed Kill Anyone in a battle?

Tags: history, prophet-muhammad, war

Everyone knows Prophet Mohammed fought in battles.

But did the Prophet Mohammed kill anyone with his own hand?

Please give proper references, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**In the name of Allah the compassionate the merciful**

Yes, The holy prophet (Peace be upon him and his household) took the life of [Ubayy bin Khalaf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubay_ibn_Khalaf). It is narrated from [Jabir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabir_ibn_Abd-Allah) as such:

Some one had domesticated a horse in Mecca. When ever the holy prophet used to pass by his place, he used to tell him:

> "I will kill you mounted on this beast"

In the battle of uhud, The holy prophet made a light scratch on his neck which was apparently not effective. but he died by this light hit of the holy prophet.

[Shaykh Tabarsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaykh_Tabarsi) narrates the whole story as following:

> ...he was **Ubayy bin Khalaf**. He moved to the Prophet with a weapon
>   saying if you escape me, may I not gain salvation. Whoever wanted to
>   confront him was restrained by the Prophet, till he came near Musayyab
>   bin Zubair and killed him with a spear. The Holy Prophet (S) took the
>   staff of Suhail bin Hanif and threw it at him and hit him near his
>   neck leaving a slight scratch and he clung to the neck of his horse
>   and ran to his company bleating like a cow.
>
> Abu Sufyan said, “Why this weeping and wailing? It is only a slight
>   scratch.” He said: “Woe be on you, don’t you know who has hit me. I
>   was attacked by Muhammad and he used to say in Mecca that he would
>   kill me. And I knew that it would be proved true one day. If such
>   scratch had been inflicted on all Meccans they all would have died.”
>   According to another report, he said: “Even if he had spat on me, I
>   would have died.” Thus the accursed one died screaming.

This event has been mentioned as one of the miracles of the holy prophet in the battle of uhud.

Answer (score 2):

Ibn Ishaq relates the story of the only person the Prophet (saws) took the life of with his own hands, and that is during the battle of Uhud: Ubai ibn Khalaf. He was one of the most detestable members of Quraish who harassed and persecuted the early Muslims in Makkah.

Comment: ♦ Any authenticated references?